# Fresh Expo Project: Unable to resolve "use-latest-callback" from "node_modules/@react-navigation/core/src/PreventRemoveProvider.tsx"

Tags: react-native, expo

I've created a fresh project with this:

```bash
npx create-expo-app@latest izmirferry --template
```

...with `Navigation (TypeScript)` option.

I do `npm run start` and scan the QR code on Expo Go on my own device, but I get an error saying:

```
Android Bundling failed 2397ms
Unable to resolve "use-latest-callback" from "node_modules/@react-navigation/core/src/PreventRemoveProvider.tsx"
Android Bundling failed 12782ms
Unable to resolve "use-latest-callback" from "node_modules/@react-navigation/core/src/PreventRemoveProvider.tsx"
```

This is a fresh project. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I just got a similar error but from React Native Paper, not from React Navigation as yours.

[image]

Needs more research to know where the bug is really from. The temp fix was to install the package directly to dev dependencies:

`npm i --save-dev use-latest-callback`